# How to add str text after using abs (unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str')

Tags: python-3.x

I can't add str text after using the abs as its giving me an error. 
How would I add 'kg' at the end of my print message.

This is for python.

```
for z in range(1, 4):
if weights_array[z - 1] > new_weights_array[z - 1]:
    print(names_array[z - 1],
          'Your weight down by: ' + str(abs(weights_array[z - 1] - new_weights_array[z - 1] + 'kg')))
elif weights_array[z - 1] < new_weights_array[z - 1]:
    print(names_array[z - 1],
          'Your weight went up by: ' + str(abs(weights_array[z - 1] - new_weights_array[z - 1] + 'kg')))
else:
    print(names_array[z - 1], 'Your weight stayed the same')
```

> 'Your weight down by: ' + str(abs(weights_array[z - 1] -
>   new_weights_array[z - 1] + 'kg'))) TypeError: unsupported operand
>   type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

I want it to add 'kg' to the end of my print statement

Comment: You are closing one parentheses too late. The term `weights_array[z - 1] - new_weights_array[z - 1] + 'kg'` is contained without any type cast in there.

Comment: so how shall i change it, i cant find where my error is coming from

Answer (score 1):

check position of the brackets:

```
print(names_array[z - 1], 'Your weight down by: ' + str(abs(weights_array[z - 1] - new_weights_array[z - 1])) + 'kg')
```

and

```
'Your weight went up by: ' + str(abs(weights_array[z - 1] - new_weights_array[z - 1])) + 'kg')
```

full code:

```
weights_array = [55,82,75,102]
new_weights_array = [60,79,76,95]
names_array = ['ana', 'john', 'david', 'mark']

for z in range(1, 4):
    if weights_array[z - 1] > new_weights_array[z - 1]:
        print(names_array[z - 1], 'Your weight down by: ' + str(abs(weights_array[z - 1] - new_weights_array[z - 1])) + 'kg')
    elif weights_array[z - 1] < new_weights_array[z - 1]:
        print(names_array[z - 1],
              'Your weight went up by: ' + str(abs(weights_array[z - 1] - new_weights_array[z - 1])) + 'kg')
    else:
        print(names_array[z - 1], 'Your weight stayed the same')
```

output:

```
ana Your weight went up by: 5kg
john Your weight down by: 3kg
david Your weight went up by: 1kg
```

NOTE:

I suggest to print in this way:

```
print ('{}, Your weight down by: {} kg'.format(names_array[z - 1],abs(weights_array[z - 1] - new_weights_array[z - 1]) ))
```

> **Basic formatting**
>
> Simple positional formatting is probably the most common use-case.
>
> ```
> Old
> '%s %s' % ('one', 'two')
> New
> '{} {}'.format('one', 'two')
> Output
> one two
>
> Old
> '%d %d' % (1, 2)
> New
> '{} {}'.format(1, 2)
> Output
> 1 2
> ```
>
> All examples on this page work out of the box with with Python 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, and 3.5 without requiring any additional libraries:
>
> https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.6 and newer use:

```
print(f"{names_array[z - 1]}, Your weight down by:  + {abs(weights_array[z - 1] - new_weights_array[z - 1])} kg")
```

Otherwise you can use format() or % operator:

```
print("{}, Your weight down by:  + {} kg}".format({names_array[z - 1], abs(weights_array[z - 1] - new_weights_array[z - 1])))
```

String concatenation via "+" is a bad practice.